# Troubleshoot jquery error with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is some sort of jquery conflict that I can't get my head around. I have a script that's working by itself here:

http://www.pitestiretailpark.ro/working.html

When the same script is inserted into a Joomla page (along with html/css code), the dropdown menus don't work.

http://www.pitestiretailpark.ro/test/

I am not a programmer, I know my HTML but have little knowledge of jquery. The standalone script has been copied from another page, stripped bare (but working!) and when I try to insert into Joomla, it stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is another lib using the `$` sign as a function.Use the jQuery.noConflict() method like this;

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

replace $ in your scripts with jQuery, also call it on document ready :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.div_btn_menu').hover(
        function() {
            jQuery(this).children('.div_sous-menu').css('top',$(this).children('.btn_menu').height()+'px')
            jQuery(this).css('z-index',10000000)
            jQuery(this).children('.div_sous-menu').stop(true,true).fadeIn(200)
        },
        function() {
            jQuery(this).css('z-index',1)
            jQuery(this).children('.div_sous-menu').stop(true,true).fadeOut(200)
        }
    );
})
```